# PowerBi - Row total in Matrix report for measures in Direct Query report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Id appreciate some help with a problem that I would otherwise be able to crack in seconds in Excel but cant wrap my brain around in PowerBI

I have direct access to a SQL database and am looking to report on the percentage of times a person attends an Appointment. A measure 'No Show' calculates if they dont as follows:

```
No Show = IF(COUNT(Candidate[bookingId]) = SUM(Candidate[deleted]),  0,1)
```

Unfortunately, this means that the total No Show for each Candidate is 1, even if they didnt attend 2 or more appointments.

I cant cant wrap my head around whats needed to get the total No Shows for the Candidate.

In the example, the expected result is 2 No Show and 66% No show %.
[Current state and Desired State]
Ive included a sample view here >> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t0x5.png)

Appreciation in advance for any help

Comment: Do you want to know how many times a candidte was not deleted?  `COUNT(Candidate[bookingId]) - SUM(Candidate[deleted])` ?

Comment: Hi Mik. Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, it didnt work as :
1. There are a multiple number of events for each bookingid (ie the same candidate may be involved in the change of a booking several times). So booking ID needed Distinct.

So for each event, I can see the result successfully (per my image) but the subtotal is incorrect. It computes there is only one event. (ie event 64333 works fine, but the roll up for 15 is incorrect.

Comment: It's not easy to get a proper picture of your data model and result you want to achive. I don't have clear picture of math and data. You can add a data sample (excel or a table in the question body ) and result sample. Let me know if you do it

Comment: Thanks Mik (and thanks for replying so fast. Will do. Ill need to do some anonymisation of the data before sharing. Please give me a few days

Comment: hej @precepri. Ok, please notify when ready.